# SharePoint 2010 workflow issues after migration to 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, migration, database-attach

I have an issue which has come up after I had a site in my companies environment migrated to SharePoint 2013 via the database attach method.

I was not part of the  migration at all from the technical side so I don't know the details there but what I do know is that we have major issues with publishing our Migrated SharePoint 2010 workflows.

Recently, we noticed that we had old versions of workflows firing on list items when they were created and it was confusing as that is not supposed to happen.

When I looked into it, I found the following:

1. Workflow is created before the database attach migration
2. Workflow is migrated and runs fine, no issues.
3. After migration the workflow is published with updates, the first time, there are no issues.
4. Upon the second or any subsequent publishing of the workflow it creates an entirely new instance of the workflow and does not disable the old instance.  If I go into list settings, I can disable the previous versions but the workflow publishing does not automatically do this. Thus if you made a few quick edits and pushing for testing, you would have 3,4,5+ versions all firing.

I did further testing and found that any 2010 workflows created native on the platform worked just fine. Only the migrated workflows were having this issue.

We reached out to our Microsoft MSE and the response was about as useless as one could get.  Essentially we were told that SP2013 supports workflows migrated from 2010 but actually it's best just to re-create the workflows (in 2010 or 2013 mode). Basically doublespeak saying 2013 does and then does not support workflows migrated from 2010.

Has anyone else had this issue or any ideas?  My next step is just to create new workflows for dozens of workflows and copy and paste all the actions from the old workflow into the new.